# Swift: How to conform to protocol with associated types if I have two types to associate?

Tags: swift, associated-types

OK weird question perhaps, and it's only because I don't really know what I'm asking for so I'll try to describe it best I can. Please direct me appropriately if this has been asked before.

So I'm using the awesome [`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) protocol with pretty much all my models and I'm making a class that handles some storing, let's call it `Storage<Model: Codable>` which has a generic type conforming to `Codable` because one instance of this class will handle storage for one type of model.

Now I need to be notified when things change in the Storage instance, like stuff getting written to disk and deletions. So I make a new protocol `StorageListener` that declares functions like `func storage(_ storage: Storage<CodableType>, didRemoveModelForKey key: String)`. Now since this uses the Storage type which requires use of a generic `Model` an associated type must be declared: `associatedtype CodableType: Codable`.

So I now use type erasure to make an `AnyStorageListener<AnyCodableType: Codable>: StorageListener`, that I can store in an array in my Storage class.
Now this is fine, I can just conform my ViewModel or whatever to `StorageListener` and declare the `typealias CodableType = MyModel` but what if I need my ViewModel to listen to two Storages of different types?

What I've come up with is using listener container objects that I can initialize with closures to the protocol functions and thus work around the problem. That should work but I was wondering if there's a cleaner solution? Perhaps some way to type erasure away the generic requirement altogether?

Comment: FWIW, to me you are maybe trying to do too much. Clearly the framework (Cocoa) should be doing this stuff. It's not. The Android team cleared the table this year and introduced a whole new set of architecture components, called Blueprint Components, take a look at them, they do this exact thing with a LiveData class that wraps entities to add observability. Not saying don't do it, but don't write a framework inside a single model.

Comment: Thanks for the perspective, do you have a link where I can check out Blueprint Components?
What I'm doing is for Swift 4, is there a way to use that in Android now?
My question is aimed to be generic in Swift 4 even though I'm mostly developing for iOS, and there is actually a way in Cocoa framework to do more general observing. In old Objective C runtime, NSObject provides an interface to observe its values. However that would require subclassing NSObject which I would like to avoid. And in this case I'm thinking more like using a custom NotificationCenter-observer like pattern.

Comment: I do here it is: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components. The docs are good but frankly checkout the intro video on YouTube. Of course you cannot use this on ios. I am saying you could benefit from seeing how they approached this exact problem. You have some good ideas. But they belong in the framework. If you do roll your own make some extensions for cocoa that your model then uses.

Comment: Thanks, interesting stuff! Yes I was thinking of putting this in a framework.